# Who has the right of way

Tags: traffic

I'm traveling down a 2 lane road.  I come to a stop sign and want to turn left onto a highway with NO stop sign.  The car behind me, traveling the same direction as me is turning right.  There is enough room for him to pull up next to me. Should he pull ahead and obstruct my vision so he can go before me, wait til I have turned left onto the highway, or pull ahead but not so much that he's obstructing my vision and I can still see cars coming from the right.

Comment: In which country? Traffic regulations vary.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining the situation. You are turning left, so you have to yield to oncoming traffic. If there is space for the other driver to pull up to the *right* of you, in which way does this impair your vision? Is the crossing you are describing a T or X crossing?

Comment: @Polygnome It's not the oncoming traffic OP is worried about; it's traffic from the right, and having a large vehicle to your immediate right can certainly obstruct your line of sight in that direction. It doesn't matter whether it's T or X.

Answer (score 3):

First, what the law says about "right of way" is who has to yield (nobody "has the right of way"). Vehicles always must yield to pedestrians. One of the principles is that you are to yield to the guy who gets there first -- if the guy on your left gets to the intersection first, you must yield to him. If you arrive at the same time, the guy on the left yields (at least in the US). The rationale is that there has to be a convention for deciding who must wait when two people want to occupy the same space in the intersection. That isn't what you are describing. You can turn left and he can turn right at the same time, and no collision should result. The other general rule is that you can turn only when it is safe to do so. If you can't see traffic coming from the left or from the right, then you can't turn. If the guy on the right is blocking your view of the right and you are blocking his view of the left, you will have to find some other social means of deciding who gets out of the way, the law doesn't help you.